# Partial differential equation/ wave equation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, wave-equation

I literally have no idea how to resolve this equation:

ψ is a real (and differentiable) function. Show that this functions satisfies the expression.
$$f(x,y)=x^2ψ(3x+y^2)\\     2xy(∂f/∂x)-3x(∂f/∂y)=4yz$$

Comment: Compute the partial derivatives of the expression for $f$ and check if the equation below is satisfied. That is all you have to do. There is a typo: it should be $4y\color{red}{f}$ not $4yz$.

Comment: typo ? $z=f$ ?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $u=3x+y^2$ then with $f(x,y)=x^2\psi(u)$ we write
$$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}=2x\psi(u)+x^2\dfrac{d\psi}{du}(3)$$
$$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}=x^2\psi(u)2y$$
With substitution you find $2xy\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}-3x\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}=4yf$.

Comment: Okay, but when i substitute the derivates it gives me 2x^2ψ(u)=0?

Comment: Or where do i have to make the substitution?

Comment: $2xy\left(2x\psi(u)+3x^2\dfrac{d\psi}{du}\right)-3x\left(2x^2y\psi(u)\right)=
4x^2y\psi(u)+6x^3y\dfrac{d\psi}{du}-6x^3y\dfrac{d\psi}{du}=4y\left(x^2\psi(u)\right)=
4yf$.